# Angular - Display *ngFor in Row and Column

Tags: css, angular, ngfor

I'm learning to use Angular and I have a problem with how to show data in columns.

In my app.components.ts I have:

```
<div class="cardComp" *ngFor="let person of people">
  <app-card-person [person]="person"></app-card-person>
</div>

// people is an array of objects
```

In my card-person.component.ts

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{person?.name}} {{person?.surname}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{person?.description}}</p>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In this way, I obtain a list of cards but they are 1 per row:

```
CARD1
CARD2
CARD3
.....
```

What I would to obtain is:

```
CARD1                        CARD2
CARD3                        CARD4
.....                        .....
```

Comment: You should say if you are using a `CSS Framework` to help the community to give the best possible answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1: Work with flexbox**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 50%;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="cardComp item" *ngFor="let person of people">
    <app-card-person [person]="person"></app-card-person>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Result

[image]

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yrux3f?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Recommended to read this [Flexbox article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

---

**Solution 2: Work with Bootstrap**

Pre-requisites: Import Bootstrap CSS file.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cardComp col-6" *ngFor="let person of people">
    <app-card-person [person]="person"></app-card-person>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Result

[image]

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ouxswl?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

## CSS Grid

In your app.component.scss

```
.cardComp {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
gap: 20px; // gap between columns
}
```